# How to solve "The specified service has been marked for deletion" error

Tags: windows-services

I try to remove a Windows Service with `sc delete <service name>`, and encounter the following error:

> [SC] DeleteService FAILED 1072:
>
> The specified service has been marked for deletion.

What I've already done:

- Stopped the service, obviously. The `sc queryex "<service name>"` gives the following result:

  ```
  SERVICE_NAME: Stub service
          TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
          STATE              : 1  STOPPED
          WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1067  (0x42b)
          SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
          CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
          WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
          PID                : 0
          FLAGS              :
  ```
- [Ensured that Microsoft Management Console is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529760/240613) (`taskkill /F /IM mmc.exe`),
- [Ensured that Event Viewer is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18467128/240613),
- [Removed the key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<service name> from the registry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2804099/240613).

  Due to this removal, `services.msc` still shows the service (with a name, but no status or startup type), but the description is “<Failed to Read Description. Error Code: 2 >”. When attempting to view the properties, “The system cannot find the file specified.” is shown five times.

The problem persists.

What is the next step?

Comment: A reboot should normally clear up any lingering state.

Comment: I know. But I thought about a less radical solution. Rebooting thirty times per day won't be an acceptable solution in my case.

Comment: Yet hacking around in the registry 30 times per day is acceptable? And why are you deleting services this regularly?

Comment: *"why are you deleting services this regularly?"*: I'm writing a Windows service. Each time it is compiled, it should be restarted. *"Yet hacking around in the registry 30 times per day is acceptable?"*: totally. Removing a key from registry doesn't force me to save everything, close every opened app, wait for a minute, and then reopen everything.

Comment: I've written windows services. Unless you're changing the actual code that performs the registration, there's no need to uninstall and reinstall it every time you do a build. So long as the path is still the same, the older registration information will still be valid.

Comment: Actually that's not a true Statement. @Damien_The_Unbeliever Microsoft has a build bug that has existed forever. You can't rebuild and deploy if it's x64. You have to edit the msi, so therefore you need to hack the registry if the state becomes corrupt. If MS had an actual reliable MSI install this wouldn't be an issue

Comment: @NickTurner - link to any bug report? Whatever bug you're referring to, I've not encountered. And I'm not sure how an MSI is involved since we're presumably talking about building and running services on a dev machine (that at least appears to be the context on this 5 year old question)

Comment: @Nick Turner: There's a well-known issue: if the MSI package is written badly, then it will block the uninstallation (including upgrade using a newer version, because this involves running the old MSI package to uninstall it); then just about the only recourse is to remove the application and its MSI components by directly editing the registry. And if one hacks around the MSI package, it's easy to make a mistake; it's much better to just rebuild it e.g. using Wix.

Answer (score 1580, accepted):

There may be several causes which lead to the service being stuck in “marked for deletion”.

1. [SysInternals' Process Explorer is opened](http://blog.cyotec.com/2011/05/specified-service-has-been-marked-for.html). Closing it should lead to automatic removal of the service.
2. [Task Manager is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20561990/how-to-solve-the-specified-service-has-been-marked-for-deletion-error/21310096#comment32672750_20565337).
3. [Microsoft Management Console (MMC) is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8529760/240613). To ensure all instances are closed, run `taskkill /F /IM mmc.exe`.
4. [Services console is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21310096/240613). This is the same as the previous point, since Services console is hosted by MMC.
5. [Event Viewer is opened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18467128/240613). Again, this is the same as the third point.
6. [The key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\{service name} exists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2804099/240613).
7. [Someone else is logged into the server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28632820/240613) and has one of the previously mentioned applications opened.
8. An instance of Visual Studio *used to debug the service* is open.

Comment: Task manager seems to do the same. And as noted below leaving the Services console open could cause this too.

Comment: ...and if closing all these still does not help and you still see the service as "marked for deletion" do simple log off instead of full restart. it helped me a few times.

Comment: One common workflow:  your nefarious colleagues are also logged into the remote server, and they all have something open...

Comment: In addition to MainMa's steps, I had to run `taskkill /F /PID pid` from an administrative cmd prompt.

Comment: Closing the services console solved this problem for me!  My process was the following: *In the VS2012 x64 Native Tools Command Prompt*  **-->**  *Navigate to directory with service exectuable*  **-->**
 *installutil /u servicename.exe (to uninstall the obsolete service)*  **-->**  *copy over new built service exe*  **-->**  *installutil servicename.exe (to install the updated service)*.  I generally can uninstall and reinstall right away with no problems. Until I randomly can't. Closing the services console solved it. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Faced the problem w/ elasticsearch 1.5.1. Only reboot helps. Looks like it happens only occasionally, sometimes I'm able to delete the service.

Comment: Process Explorer is the big one here, in my opinion. I suggest bolding it and/or moving it to the top of the list.

Comment: In addition to that, I had to run `sc stop "Task Name"` and wait for the error message, until the `sc delete` worked.

Comment: Log off and log on again resolved this issue for me.

Comment: I had a config file for my service open in Notepad, under another user's session.  Signed out, logged in under that user, closed Notepad, and my previous uninstallation I did through Program and Features (Add/Remove Programs) finally finished.

Comment: Very helpful, especially for a server environment where rebooting the machine is not an option.

Comment: I just Ended the Service name task and it's fine. Looks like it had file permissions when deleting the temp files for cleanup.

Comment: @Arseni Mourzenko, on point 7 "Someone else is logged into the server and has one of the previously mentioned applications opened." I doubt it. What about someone else already logged out, but opened them before logout?

Comment: @Pingpong: if the user logs out, all the applications he opened during his session are closed.

Comment: confirming @LC answer. closing services window didn't work but "stop-service" on the supposedly deleted service did.

Comment: For me having the Service Console open what the issue.  Closed that and the issue went away.

Comment: Why the hell would having the services console open cause this error to delete then install the service in powershell....  Well it seemed to work for me!

Comment: Testing the above techniques on Windows 11 ARM64 did not work.  The services console and task manager were open, but closing them did nothing to resolve the OP's issue.  The pid was 0 when queried, so this could not be killed.  Instead, I had to close `cmd.exe`, the process which installed the service.

Comment: Closing Visual Studio seems to have done the trick for me. Still cannot believe it haha. Thank you

Comment: i had to open the Services Console, stop the offending process, and only then it went away.

Answer (score 339):

This can also be caused by leaving the Services console open.  Windows won't actually delete the service until it is closed.

Comment: As I indicated in my question, “Microsoft Management Console is closed” during the tests.

Comment: In my case the Services console was the problem. As soon as I closed it and reopened it the deleted services went away.

Comment: Hard to believe that keeping the window open was the case... Thank you!

Comment: This worked for me too, although strangely there's been plenty of cases where simply pressing F5 will refresh the list with the service removed.

Comment: After doing this, right button on the service and close all tasks solved the problem for me.

Comment: This still applies a decade later!

Answer (score 85):

In my case, it worked after closing the `Services` window and verifying that the service had no processes open. Check if the `Services.msc` window is open. If so, close it. Then check the `Task Manager` to see if the service in question has any processes running. If so, kill them by right clicking on each one and choosing "End Task" from the context menu.

Comment: IT WORKED for me !! The service process still lingered on in the task manager, I first closed the services console, then deleted the service process from Task manager. Then reopened services console to see the service gone!

Comment: This was the culprit for me too, and had it not worked, I would have tested with closing Visual Studio.

Comment: If there is no PID, I believe most of the time this will be the issue.

Answer (score 73):

I had the same problem, finally I decided to kill the service process.

Tried below steps to achieve the outcome:

- get process id of service with

  `sc queryex <service name>`
- kill process with

  `taskkill /F /PID <Service PID>`

Comment: my PID is 0 so I had better not kill that!

Comment: you can uninstall service  for it do below steps
1- run cmd
2- change direction to .exe file of your service locate that
3- execute command installutil /u <yourfilename.exe>

Comment: +1 for sc queryex
I'll be able to use that to get the PID if I want to attach the debugger

Comment: Using an administrator mode command prompt is recommended.

Answer (score 24):

Closing the services console as suggested by a few of the answers here did allow me to remove the service. In my scenario this was only a short term fix since all subsequent reinstalls and removal of the service would require me to take these additional steps. Reviewing my web.config file, it was discovered that there was an error that once fixed, allowed me to easily remove the service without the additional closing of the services console step.

Answer (score 18):

That means the service is still listed as disabled in services.msc.
Just close the services.msc and re open as administrator...
The service will not be listed. Now, install the service using the command,

installutil  "path of service"

Comment: easiest solution ever :)

Comment: I just had to reopen my services.msc and it's gone. thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Deleting registry keys as suggested above got my service stuck in the stopping state. The following procedure worked for me:

open task manager > select services tab > select the service > right click and select "go to process" > right click on the process and select End process

Service should be gone after that

Answer (score 9):

Discovered one more thing to check - look in Task  manager - if other users are connected to this box, even if they are 'disconnected' you have to actually sign them out to get the service to finally delete.

Comment: Unnecessary. You just have to ensure everybody exits the Microsoft Management Console (MMC) and Services control panel.

Answer (score 8):

Closing every window that was currently open followed by running the following command solved the issue for me:

```
taskkill /F /IM mmc.exe
```

Answer (score 7):

It seems that on Windows versions later than Windows 7 (unverified, but by experience latest with Windows Server 2012 R2), the Service Control Manager (SCM) is more strict.

While on Windows 7 it just spawns another process, it is now checking whether the service process is still around and may return ERROR_SERVICE_MARKED_FOR_DELETE (1072) for any subsequent call to CreateService/DeleteService even if the service appears to be stopped.

I am talking Windows API code here, but I want to clearly outline what's happening, so this sequence may lead to mentioned error:

```cpp
SC_HANDLE hScm = OpenSCManager(nullptr, nullptr, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

SC_HANDLE hSvc = OpenService(hScm, L"Stub service", SERVICE_STOP | SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS | DELETE);

SERVICE_STATUS ss;
ControlService(hSvc, SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP, &ss);
// ... wait for service to report its SERVICE_STOPPED state

DeleteService(hSvc);
CloseServiceHandle(hSvc);
hSvc = nullptr;

// any further calls to CreateService/DeleteService will fail
// if service process is still around
```

The reason a service process is still around after it already has reported its SERVICE_STOPPED state isn't surprising. It's a regular process, whose main thread is 'stuck' in its call to the `StartServiceCtrlDispatcher` API, so it first reacts to a stop control action, but then has to execute its remaining code sequence.

It's kind of unfortunate the SCM/OS isn't handling this properly for us.
A programmatic solution is kinda simple and accurate: obtain the service executable's process handle before stopping the service, then wait for this handle to become signaled.

If approaching the issue from a system administration perspective the solution is also to wait for the service process to disappear completely.

Answer (score 6):

This is what worked for me:
- I hit the same issue: my service was stuck in 'marked for deletion'.
- I opened services.msc
  My service did show up as running, although it was already uninstalled.
- I clicked Stop
  Received an error message, saying the service is not in a state to receive control messages.
  Nevertheless, the service was stopped.
- Closed services.msc.
- Reopened services.msc.
  - The service was gone (no longer showing in the list of services).

(The environment was Windows 7.)

Comment: Windows 2008 here, I had to just close the services panel

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I execute `taskkill /f /im dongleserver.exe` , 
where `dongleserver.exe` is my program's exe file.

Then I can able to reinstall my program already.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was caused by unhandled exception while creating eventLog source. Use try catch to pin point the cause.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

- Open Task Manager
- Select services tab
- Select the service with the issue
- Right click and select "Go to details"
- Right click on the service and select "End process tree"

End process tree will end the process and all the processes created by the process.

Then, you can reinstall the service.

Answer (score 2):

**steps to follow:**

**step-1** goto the location C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319

**step-2** run command:  installutil /u full-path/servicename.exe

**step-3** close services panel and reopen it

**step-4** run command:  installutil full-path/servicename.exe

Comment: a side note: installutil works ONLY as admin, so open a shell as admin.

Comment: When my service ended up in a marked for deletion state and I couldn't manage to get its registration deleted using any of the other solutions here, this worked for me!

Comment: I just do the step 3, close services panel[include task manager]. Then OK. [SC] OpenService FAILED 1060:

The specified service does not exist as an installed service.

Comment: @DivyangShah Yes, but I only did the third step and solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the service name was 'Monitor' which is also used by a windows service called 'Monitor', when I tried to update my services, I tried uninstalling them, the installer tried to remove the windows service 'Monitor' which it couldn't, and the installation was always rolled back.

I ended up renaming my service to something else

Answer (score 1):

The main reason for the error is the process is not stopped.
to resolve it  start task manager go to services and see if you are still able to see your service than go to the process of that service and end process. Than the issue will be solved completely.

Answer (score 0):

If the steps provided by @MainMa didn't work follow following steps

Step 1 Try killing the process from windows task manager or using taskkill /F /PID  . You can find pid of the process by command 'sc queryex '. Try next step if you still can't uninstall.

Step 2 If above

Run [Autoruns for Windows](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) Search for service by name and delete results.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue when I was using Application Verifier to verify my win service. Even after I closed App Ver my service was blocked from deletion. Only removing the service from App Ver resolved the issue and service was deleted right away. Looks like some process still using your service after you tried to delete one.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably deleting service fails because

```
protected override void OnStop()
```

throw error when stopping a service. wrapping things inside a try catch will prevent mark for deletion error

```
protected override void OnStop()
{
            try
            {
                //things to do
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this could happen during service deletion via PowerShell remote session script, especially when you are trying to delete service several times. In this case, try to recreate a session before the deletion:

```
Remove-PSSession -Session $session
$newSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Name  -Credential $creds -ErrorAction Stop
Enter-PSSession $newSession
```